# How to read or get image file from local folder(disk storage) and send it to Angularjs using nodejs server?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js, image

I've been trying to get a image file from my folder and give it to my Angular UI using Node server, nodejs reads the image file as buffer format but how to send it to angular code? and how to use it in html page?

HTML

`<img class="img img-thumbnail img-responsive" ng-src="{{imager}}"/>`

Angular code:

```
$http.get("/getimages").success(function(data) {
    $scope.imager=$parse(data);
}).error(function(data) {
    console.log(data)
});
```

Node server code:

```
app.get("/getimages",function(req,res) {
    var myfiles=fs.readFileSync("./fromnode/image1.jpg");
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/jpg' });
    res.end(myfiles, 'binary');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

using `input:file`

click input brower file,change file submit to server;

```
<input type="file" id="J_uploadFile" style="display:none;" />
<script>
var $options = {
        type: 'POST',
        url: window.URL.uploadfile,  //setting you server image upload url
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        crossDomain: true,
        processData: false,  // tell jQuery don't 
        contentType: false,   // tell jQuery don't setting Content-Type request header
        dataType: "json"
    };
$("#J_uploadFile").bind({
            change: function () {
                var formdata = new FormData();
                $.each($('#J_uploadFile')[0].files, function (i, file) {
                    formdata.append('files', file);
                });
                $options.data=formdata;
                $options.success = function (result) {
                    console.log(result);
                };
                $.ajax($options);
            }
        });
</script>
```

angularjs ,you can use `angular-plupload.min.js`.
nodejs server，use `npm install formidable@latest`
nodejs code

```
var formidable = require('formidable'),
http = require('http'),
util = require('util');

//use http module create http client 
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  if (req.url == '/upload'&&req.method.toLowerCase() === 'post') {
    // get file
   var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

  form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
    res.write('received upload:\n\n');
    res.end(util.inspect({fields: fields, files: files}));
  });

  return;
 }

}).listen(8080);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I want to do it in Angularjs, Nodejs and Html only, do you have any answer on i mentioned libraries? kindly post it ..